# Using r, transform wide survey data into long, given participants' answers to similar questions were captured in different columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, survey

I would like to transform survey data from a wide format into a long one, in particular summarizing several columns that are the same questions, yet are separated by the survey tool into different columns, based on a previous filter-question, that filtered the participants accordingly.

Previously I tried to tackle the problem using tidyr's gather() function. The problem is that I have a huge number of columns to gather and I do not want to manually specify every single column to gather.

I created a sample dataframe to showcase my problem

```
library(data.table)

a1 <- rep(0,10)
a2 <- c(1:10)

b1 <- c(a2,a1,a1) 
b2 <- c(a1,a2,a1)
b3 <- c(a1,a1,a2)

df <-transpose(data.frame(b1,b2,b3))
```

The dataframe shows 30 columns representing 10 questions for three participants, all after another.

Ideally, the final dataframe should look like this:

```
library(data.table)
a2 <- c(1:10)
df2 <- transpose(data.frame(a2,a2,a2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a shorter way, but here's a tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  gather(col, val, -id) %>%
  filter(val != 0) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0("V", str_pad(row_number(), width = 2, pad = 0))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(col, val)

# A tibble: 3 x 11
     id   V01   V02   V03   V04   V05   V06   V07   V08   V09   V10
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
2     2     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
3     3     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Comment: thank you Jon, the original dataframe as about 500 columns, among which an ID, so I could just use that one.